# SQL multi-table query guidance

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have the following query:

```
SELECT
    _RES_COLL_EVM00012.MachineID,
    _RES_COLL_EVM00012.Name,
    v_GS_NETWORK_ADAPTER_CONFIGUR.IPAddress0,
    v_GS_NETWORK_ADAPTER_CONFIGUR.DefaultIPGateway0,
    v_GS_NETWORK_ADAPTER_CONFIGUR.TimeStamp,
    v_GS_NETWORK_ADAPTER_CONFIGUR.RevisionID
FROM
    _RES_COLL_EVM00012
    LEFT JOIN v_GS_NETWORK_ADAPTER_CONFIGUR
    ON _RES_COLL_EVM00012.MachineID = v_GS_NETWORK_ADAPTER_CONFIGUR.ResourceID
WHERE
    v_GS_NETWORK_ADAPTER_CONFIGUR.IPEnabled0 = 1
    AND v_GS_NETWORK_ADAPTER_CONFIGUR.IPAddress0 != '0.0.0.0'
    AND v_GS_NETWORK_ADAPTER_CONFIGUR.IPAddress0 IS NOT NULL
    AND v_GS_NETWORK_ADAPTER_CONFIGUR.DefaultIPGateway0 != '0.0.0.0'
    AND v_GS_NETWORK_ADAPTER_CONFIGUR.DefaultIPGateway0 IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY
    _RES_COLL_EVM00012.Name ASC,
    v_GS_NETWORK_ADAPTER_CONFIGUR.TimeStamp DESC, 
    v_GS_NETWORK_ADAPTER_CONFIGUR.RevisionID DESC
```

Which returns something like the following:

```
MachineID  Name     IPAddress0       DefaultGatewayIP0          TimeStamp   RevisionID
16777323   CTNB21   192.168.17.134   192.168.17.254    9/09/2013 13:07:11    8
16777323   CTNB21   192.168.17.143   192.168.17.254    9/09/2013 13:07:11    6
16777585   CTNB26   192.168.16.106   192.168.16.254   28/10/2013 22:39:55   33
16777585   CTNB26   192.168.16.116   192.168.16.254   28/10/2013 22:39:55   27
```

Obviously ResourceID is not unique in the table v_GS_NETWORK_ADAPTER_CONFIGUR. What I need to do is display every row from the table _RES_COLL_EVM00012 along with a SINGLE row for each from v_GS_NETWORK_ADAPTER_CONFIGUR.

The row selected from v_GS_NETWORK_ADAPTER_CONFIGUR should be the one with the most recent TimeStamp and the greatest RevisionID.

Note also I do not actually want to select MachineID, TimeStamp or RevisionID, I have just done so to help better explain my request.

One more thing, if a row does not exist in v_GS_NETWORK_ADAPTER_CONFIGUR with a match for the MachineID/ResourceID, I still need to output the Name but with blank values for IPAddress0 and DefaultGatewayIP0

So to clarify I would like the example result set to look like this instead:

```
Name      IPAddress0        DefaultGatewayIP0
CTNB21    192.168.17.134    192.168.17.254
CTNB26    192.168.16.106    192.168.16.254
```

Comment: Er, for your future reference, please note that a table referenced with a `LEFT JOIN` that then has a **required** comparison in the `WHERE` clause (... such as `v_GS_NETWORK_ADAPTER_CONFIGUR.IPEnabled0 = 1`...) will be essentially turned into a regular `INNER JOIN`.  Whenever you do a join, put as many comparisons as possible into the actual join conditions, specifically to avoid this sort of thing (note that there are ways around this behavior, but aren't usually required).  Also, is `RevisionID` _always_ final differentiator (what's the effective `ORDER BY` for 'most recent)?

Answer (score 0):

Use DENSE_RANK()OVER(PARTITION BY RevisionID,TimeStamp ORDER BY RevisionID,TimeStamp DESC) in select statement as below.

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT _RES_COLL_EVM00012.MachineID,
             _RES_COLL_EVM00012.Name,
             v_GS_NETWORK_ADAPTER_CONFIGUR.IPAddress0,
             v_GS_NETWORK_ADAPTER_CONFIGUR.DefaultIPGateway0,
             v_GS_NETWORK_ADAPTER_CONFIGUR.TimeStamp,
             v_GS_NETWORK_ADAPTER_CONFIGUR.RevisionID,
             DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY RevisionID, TimeStamp 
                                ORDER BY RevisionID, TimeStamp DESC) RowID
      FROM _RES_COLL_EVM00012
      LEFT JOIN v_GS_NETWORK_ADAPTER_CONFIGUR
             ON _RES_COLL_EVM00012.MachineID = v_GS_NETWORK_ADAPTER_CONFIGUR.ResourceID
     WHERE v_GS_NETWORK_ADAPTER_CONFIGUR.IPEnabled0 = 1
           AND v_GS_NETWORK_ADAPTER_CONFIGUR.IPAddress0 != '0.0.0.0'
           AND v_GS_NETWORK_ADAPTER_CONFIGUR.IPAddress0 IS NOT NULL
           AND v_GS_NETWORK_ADAPTER_CONFIGUR.DefaultIPGateway0 != '0.0.0.0'
           AND v_GS_NETWORK_ADAPTER_CONFIGUR.DefaultIPGateway0 IS NOT NULL
     ) XYZ
WHERE XYZ.RowID = 1
```

For more articles on SQL Server please visit [SQL Server Basics](http://borngeek.in)

Comment: Please learn how to format your queries.  `DENSE_RANK()` generates 'duplicate' ranks, so I'd prefer `ROW_NUMBER()` (granted, `RevisionId` makes this particular problem unlikely).  The OP doesn't actually need all the columns you're returning (and please, always explicitly list columns).  Also, the conditions in the `WHERE` clause are going to turn that `LEFT JOIN` into essentially a regular `INNER JOIN`.  As a personal preference, I prefer to do the 'most recent row', as soon as possible, to limit the potential number of rows generated by a join.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    --_RES_COLL_EVM00012.MachineID,
    _RES_COLL_EVM00012.Name,
    ISNULL(v_GS_NETWORK_ADAPTER_CONFIGUR.IPAddress0,'') as IPAddress0,
    ISNULL(v_GS_NETWORK_ADAPTER_CONFIGUR.DefaultIPGateway0,'') as DefaultIPGateway0
    --v_GS_NETWORK_ADAPTER_CONFIGUR.TimeStamp,
    --v_GS_NETWORK_ADAPTER_CONFIGUR.RevisionID
FROM
    _RES_COLL_EVM00012
    LEFT JOIN v_GS_NETWORK_ADAPTER_CONFIGUR
    ON _RES_COLL_EVM00012.MachineID = v_GS_NETWORK_ADAPTER_CONFIGUR.ResourceID
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT a.ResourceID,a.RevisionID, MAX(a.TimeStamp) as TimeStamp
                FROM v_GS_NETWORK_ADAPTER_CONFIGUR a
                    join (SELECT ResourceID, MAX(RevisionID) as RevisionID
                        FROM v_GS_NETWORK_ADAPTER_CONFIGUR
                        GROUP BY ResourceID) b
                    ON a.ResourceID=b.ResourceID
                                  GROUP BY a.ResourceID,a.RevisionID
                )c
    ON v_GS_NETWORK_ADAPTER_CONFIGUR.ResourceID=c.ResourceID
        AND v_GS_NETWORK_ADAPTER_CONFIGUR.RevisionID=c.RevisionID
        AND v_GS_NETWORK_ADAPTER_CONFIGUR.TimeStamp=c.TimeStamp
WHERE
    c.RevisionID IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY
    _RES_COLL_EVM00012.Name ASC,
    v_GS_NETWORK_ADAPTER_CONFIGUR.TimeStamp DESC, 
    v_GS_NETWORK_ADAPTER_CONFIGUR.RevisionID DESC
```

Comment: #winces#... well, as a first run goes, this isn't too bad.  Look up OLAP functions (specifically, you'll want the `OVER()` clause).  Also, there might not always be a row in `v_GS_NETWORK_ADAPTER_CONFIGUR` **at all**, so the `IS NOT NULL` check isn't going to work out.